# Does a Factory Reset damages my laptop's SSD?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, ssd

First of all any replies are very much appreciated.
So, I actually rekted my laptop by going to regedit and change the user folder's name, after that my laptop was not able to sign into desktop. Because of this i did a factory reset (I chose the option to keep all files) The laptop was able to boot after a factory reset. However, because of windows.old being present, i did another factory reset twice (Remove all files because I didnt like the idea of having the windows.old folder there). My question is,  will this damage my SSD? And how do I get rid completely of the windows.old folder? Thankyou. My windows is Windows 10 version.

Answer (score 1):

Other than producing unnecessary activity on the SSD that can technically reduce it's life, no it will not hurt your SSD anymore than any other type of disk activity. And the amount of reduction in life, is most likely not significant for common, everyday use.

To remove the windows.old folder you can just delete it. It is a copy of the old Windows installation before you did an "in place upgrade," which is pretty much what a reset is.

You can also remove it by using "disk cleanup" and choosing the option to remove "Previous Windows Installation(s)"

Don't remove the Windows.old folder if there is any possibility you might want to roll back the upgrade you did.